# playframework 2.x how to do basic authentication for application/json requests?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

We would like to do form authentication for users for basic and I think we could work through the zentasks sample for that.  How do we do basic authentication so programs can programmatically pre-empt the challenge and not deal with form authentication at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never mind, found something perfect and it worked great...

http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/06/07/basic-authentication-in-the-play-framework-using-custom-action-annotation/

Comment: It worked great but there are warning because of the use of `new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth);` which is an internal method.

To avoid this, simply use `Base64.getDecoder().decode(auth)` instead (Java 8)

Answer (score 0):

I created a example implementation of Basic Authentication using Play Framework Filters with Scala.  Here is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dk8996/1fd2497e82297dad5789) and here is a [blog post](http://www.mentful.com/2014/06/14/basic-authentication-filter-for-play-framework/).